# How to read one whole line from text file using <

Tags: c, gcc, file-io

I am trying to get one whole line from some text file instead of one word until it meets white space, here is source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  int lineNum=0;
  char lineContent[100];

  scanf("%s", &lineContent);
  printf("%s\n", lineContent);
}
```

And here is my text file, called test.txt, content containing 2 lines:

```
111 John Smith 100 98 1.2 2.5 3.6
222 Bob  Smith 90 91 3.2 6.5 9.6
```

And I run it with following command:

```
a.out < test.txt
```

My output is just:

```
111
```

What I want is:

```
111 John Smith 100 98 1.2 2.5 3.6
```

Of course, I can simply use while statement and read recursively until it meets EOF, but that is not what I want. I just want to read one whole line per each time I read from file.

How can I do this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: (1) Use `fgets` : `scanf("%s", &lineContent);
printf("%s\n", lineContent);` --> `fgets(lineContent, sizeof lineContent, stdin);
printf("%s", lineContent);`. Also `while(fgets(...) != NULL) fputs(lineContent, stdout);`

Comment: (2) `scanf("%s", &lineContent);` --> `scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", lineContent);`. Also `while(1==scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", lineContent)) printf("%s\n", lineContent);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fgets()` is the most convenient standard library function for reading files one line at a time.  GNU `getline()` is even more convenient, but it is non-standard.

If you want to use `scanf()`, however, then you can do so by using the `[` field descriptor instead of `s`:

```
char lineContent[100];

scanf("%99[^\n]", &lineContent);
getchar();
```

Note the use of an explicit field width to protect against overrunning the bounds of `lineContent` in the event that a long line is encountered.  Note also that the `[` descriptor differs from `s` in that `[` does not skip leading whitespace.  If preserving leading whitespace is important to you, then `scanf` with an `s` field is a non-starter.

The `getchar()` reads the terminating newline, presuming that there is one, and that `scanf()` did not read 99 characters without reaching the end of the line.

Comment: posix has getline

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read line by line, then use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) or [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html) (available on POSIX systems) instead of `scanf()`. `scanf()` stops at first whitespace (or matching failure) for `%s`.